# omniture 10/17 release - anyone experience the following issues?

Tags: adobe-analytics

On 10/17, adobe issued release 1.4 (Version 15), which wrote over all of our event, evar and prop field names... has anyone else experienced this issue?  If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this happen (I work with a lot of clients who use SiteCatalyst.. haven't heard anything from them nor seen it myself).  I would first try logging out and clearing cache/cookies and then log back in.  I have sometimes noticed weird behavior in menus after changes (like creating/updating saint classifications), and doing this fixes it.  But if that doesn't work, you can just go into your interface and relabel them (you have to have admin privs). Kinda inconvenient, but doable.

Also.. if there is more than one person with admin access to your SC interface.. you should ask around and see if anybody messed with it. Another way this could happen is for example if someone made a new report suite and was looking to dupe the variable labels/settings from an existing one.. and then messed up the process. For example, if you select 2 (or more rsids) and go into the prop listing, it will normally say "multiple" as a value if they do not match up between rsids.. but when you make a change, it's changing all selected rsids..

Comment: To add to the admin interface portion - you can always take a look at the logs (Admin Tools > Logs > Report Suite Change Log)